# Running tomcat6 webapp with privileges

Tags: linux, tomcat, websocket

I'm running jWebSockets on tomcat6 and when it comes up this line appears in the log:

`2012-10-13 23:04:52,298 ERROR - FlashBridgePlugIn: FlashBridge could not be started: Permission denied`

some digging around and I found that since this plugin runs a FlashPolicyServer and it needs to use port 843, It needs root privileges. How do I give root privileges to a webapp? Can I just give enough privileges to the TOMCAT_USER so it will be able to use ports below 1024?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html). It can be used to launch Tomcat to allow it to do some root-y things such as bind to low-numbered ports.

I'm not exactly sure at what point jsvc/Tomcat conspire to drop root privileges: your webapp might not have a chance to open that port before the privileges are dropped. In that case, I think you'll have to write your own bootstrap (Java) class similar to the stock Tomcat one and use *that* with jsvc. Then, you can allow your webapp to open that port before shedding root privileges.

Comment: I'm taking your advise, but I can't seem to get tomcat running with jsvc. I've installed jsvc using synaptic. And I'm trying to run tomcat using the command here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/setup.html  but I'm getting errors: `Unable to redirect to ./logs/catalina.out` and `Cannot open PID file /var/run/jsvc.pid, PID is 2404` and eventually: `Service exit with a return value of 255` Can you help with this?

Comment: Don't forget to run jsvc as `root` ;)

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I'm still encountering some errors. I have a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887028/ think you could take a look?

Comment: scratch that last comment, I have it working now. However, it seems that like you said the root privileges have probably dropped before my webapp had a chance to open the port. Can you give me more info about what needs to be done with the bootstrap class to have it wait? the bootstrap.jar file I have contains only .class files, so I'm guessing I'll have to download some kind of sample?

Comment: You'll have to download the Tomcat source to see what the Bootstrap class does. Now would be a great time to upgrade to Tomcat 7: it compiles *much* more easily than Tomcat 6 does for a newbie and the embedded options are also much better and easier to use. Definitely join the Tomcat users' mailing list to get better direction than I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Port 843 is the fallback port, have you tried to check if port 8787 is open. Please see [documentation here](http://jwebsocket.org/downloads/dl_latest.htm).

Comment: I am assuming 8787 is open because in general the jwebsocket server works (for example in chrome as client). However, I don't see how this would explain the fact the flashbrige cannot be loaded with the "permission denied" error